# What to make testing automation using Bamboo server

Tags: selenium

So far we have been doing manual testing, now We are trying to make testing automation in our Organization. We would like  to use bamboo server with Selenium cucumber to achieve this.

We have developed some feature file for the scenarios and generated selenium webdriver scripts. we are able to run this automated scripts with eclipse environment.

Now we would like to execute this scripts on the Bamboo server for continuous integration. We are not sure how to proceed with this like do we need to convert the selenium scripts to Junit tests and run them on Bamboo using Junit parser etc.

Please help us to achieve this level of autoamation.

Comment: are you using build management tool? Like maven or ant?

Comment: yes we have been using Ant tool

Answer (score 0):

Setup Cucumber with Maven.In Bamboo build plan use Maven task to run it. For getting results in Bamboo use Cucumber Task for Bamboo. It will convert Cucumber scenarios in tests in Bamboo. If scenario names contains JIRA issue ids, it will link them to JIRA issues.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.mdb.plugins.cucumberforbamboo/server/overview